# Orientdb hooks - callback for client

Tags: orientdb

Is it possible to register a hook from a client connected to remotely running orientdb instance and get callback for any update on a particular document change

right now i am able to register the hook from client by following document [self registration](http://orientdb.com/docs/2.1/Java-Hooks.html#self-registration)

will this give callback , if i do some modifications on the registered document using console or studio ?

Answer (score 1):

This isn't possible, but you can instead using Live Queries: http://orientdb.com/docs/last/Live-Query.html

Comment: Thank you Luca ., live query seems to be proper way n will solve the problem

Comment: i am getting below error when i try to query live data 
`code` : 
`List<ODocument> result = db.getRawGraph().query(new OLiveQuery<ODocument>("live select from TEST", listener));`
ERROR : 
`
com.orientechnologies.orient.core.command.OCommandExecutorNotFoundException: Cannot find a command executor for the command request: sql.live select from TEST`

@lcva can you please help

Comment: i missed the statement mentioned in document to enable live query plugin since i am using 2.1.5 , 

`<handler class="com.orientechnologies.orient.server.plugin.livequery.OLiveQueryPlugin">
            <parameters>
                <parameter value="true" name="enabled"/>
            </parameters>
        </handler>`

sorry for the trouble ,